# Gulp task with loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have such JSON

```
[
  {"replacement": "str1", "destination": "dir1"},
  {"replacement": "str2", "destination": "dir2"},
  {"replacement": "str3", "destination": "dir3"},
  {"replacement": "str4", "destination": "dir4"}
]
```

and quite simple gulp task

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('mytask', function() {
  return gulp.src('myfile.txt')
    .pipe(replace(/foo(.{3})/g, replacement))  // take `replacement` from json
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));             // take `destination` from json
});
```

I need run this stuff in loop. I need either call this task from the `default` task several times with different params or implement loop inside the `mytask` task.